# Creating project in Phalcon 3.2 is php version specific i.e. php 5.6 or php 7.0

Tags: phalcon, php-7, php-5.6

**In short :** So if I install php5-phalcon (3.2) on local machine with php 5.6, can I easily move code to machine with php7.0 or is code version specific?

**Detail scenario :**

***Local machine has following configuration :***

```
Ubuntu 14.04
PHP 5.6
Phalcon 3.2.2 (installed using command php5-phalcon)
Phalcon devtools 3.2.5
```

***Docker Image / Server Image has following config :***

```
Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.0
Phalcon 3.2.2 (installed using command php7.0-phalcon)
Phalcon devtools 3.2.5
```

My concern here is that if I create skeleton and work on that using phalcon at local machine, will those same files and skeleton work on Docker/Server machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Phalcon 3.2.2 is [supported](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/v3.2.2#linuxunixmac) on both PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0. So either of your machines will work as expected. However, I'll advice that you run the same version of PHP and Phalcon your environments to prevent inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my question was whether code developed on php 5.6 will work on php 7.0.  Btw found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's like any other php extension in the sense that it is built for your current version of php.

You just don't install it using pecl.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it will work with both php version irrespective where I write code. In details answer can be found : https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues/1106